# val en datepicker

Tags: javascript, kotlin, datepicker

A ver, tengo una variable con la fecha de hoy y que muestro en un textView *tv_Fecha

```
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    var day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    var month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    var year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)

    val current = LocalDateTime.now()
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, dd-M-yyyy")
    val formatterPath = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val formatted = current.format(formatter)
    val formattedPath = current.format(formatterPath)

    var fecha: String = formatted
    val v: String = "json"

    tv_Fecha.setText(formatted)
```

Y que tambien uso esta variabe para enviar como parametro para completar una url

```
viewModelGuia = getViewModel(fecha, v)
```

Bueno mi problema es, Cuando selecciono una fecha en un datePicker, Como puedo hacer que la variable *fecha me de el valor del *date picker?

```
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    var day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    var month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    var year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)

    val current = LocalDateTime.now()
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, dd-M-yyyy")
    val formatterPath = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val formatted = current.format(formatter)
    val formattedPath = current.format(formatterPath)

    var fecha: String = formattedPath
    val v: String = "json"

    tv_Fecha.setText(formatted)

    println("fecha antes del datePicker: " +  fecha)

        btn_fecha.setOnClickListener(){
            val dpd = DatePickerDialog(
                context,
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { datePicker, selyear, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                    day = dayOfMonth
                    month = monthOfYear + 1
                    year = selyear

                    tv_Fecha.text = "$day - $month - $year"
                    fecha = "$year-0$month-$day"

                    println("La fecha dentro del datePiker que es la que quiero enviar como parametro: " +  fecha)

                }, year, month, day
            )
            dpd.show()
        }

    val apiService : Interface = TheJsonDBClient.getClientGuia()

    println("la fecha que recibo en el viewModel: " +  fecha)

    guiaRepositoryGuia = GuiaPagedListRepositoryMovis(apiService)
    viewModelGuia = getViewModel(fecha, v)

    val movieAdapter = GuiaAdapterMovis(context!!)
```

Continua........>>>>>>>

Logcat antes del click

> 2020-06-18 05:21:59.098 27210-27210/rafelcf.pelis I/System.out: fecha
> antes del datePicker: 2020-06-18 2020-06-18 05:21:59.102
> 27210-27210/rafelcf.pelis I/System.out: la fecha que recibo en el
> viewModel: 2020-06-18

Logcat despues del click

> 2020-06-18 05:22:13.873 27210-27210/rafelcf.pelis I/System.out: La
> fecha dentro del datePiker que es la que quiero enviar como parametro:
> 2020-06-21

pues esta es la que quiero enviar pero por lo visto me sigue enviando la fecha actualn no la fecha del datePicker.

```
class GuiaViewModelMovis(
    private val guiaRepositoryGuia: GuiaPagedListRepositoryMovis,
    fecha: String,
    v: String
) : ViewModel() {

    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    val  guiaPagedList : LiveData<PagedList<GuiaTv>> by lazy {
        guiaRepositoryGuia.fetchLiveMoviePagedList(compositeDisposable, fecha, v)
    }

    val  networkState : LiveData<NetworkState> by lazy {
        guiaRepositoryGuia.getNetworkState()
    }

    fun listIsEmpty(): Boolean {
        return guiaPagedList.value?.isEmpty() ?: true
    }


    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        compositeDisposable.dispose()
    }

}
```

el viewModel me referia a esta linea:

```
viewModelGuia = getViewModel(fecha, v)
```

Comment: Hola Rafa en realidad lo estas haciendo correctamente,  cual es el problema, que obtienes en la variable fecha?

Comment: Post 1 editado, no recibo la fecha del datePicker en el viewModel

Comment: Agrega tu ViewModel por favor

Comment: arriba esta puesto